# Append old chats before new chats to the div using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function, codeigniter

In my online-chat project using Codeigniter, jQuery, AJAX I have a **function that runs every 1 second** which retrieves chat with delivered status = 0

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>chat/admin_chat/get_chat",
{ 
  user_id : $('.hide_me').text(),
  username : $('.username').text()                              
},
function(data){
  if (data != "") {
        $('#chat_window').append(data);
        $('#chat_window').scrollTop($('#chat_window').prop("scrollHeight"));
  }
}
);
```

and there is another **function which is used to get the chats with delivered status = 1** (or old chats),

```
$(document).on('click','.user',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.username').html($(this).text());
    $('.hide_me').html($(this).attr('id'));             
    $('.username').show();
    $('.log_username').hide();
    $("#input").removeAttr("readonly");
    var user = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#chat_window").html('');
    $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>chat/admin_chat/get_old_chat",
        { 
            user_id : $('.hide_me').text(),
            username : $('.username').text()
        },
        function(data){
            $('#chat_window').append(data);
            $('#chat_window').scrollTop($('#chat_window').prop("scrollHeight"));
        }
    );
});
```

which is called **when clicked on the username**. The result of both AJAX calls are appended to a div. The problem I face now is sometimes when I click on the username, the **chats that are not delivered is getting appended to the div before the old chats** *which is not what I want*. I need the old chats to be appended to the div before the new chats, when clicked on the username. Could someone please suggest a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a way to fix the issue.

1. I added a span `<span id='old_chat_appended' hidden=""></span>`.
2. Modified the `get_old_chat` function a little bit by changing the value of span to 0 and 1. 
   After `e.preventDefault()`, **added**

   `$('#old_chat_appended').text('0')`

   and after appending data to div using `$('#chat_window').append(data)`, **added**

   `$('#old_chat_appended').text('1')`.
3. At last in the `get_chat` function, which runs every 1 second, **added**

   `if($('#old_chat_appended').text() == 1)
   {
       $('#chat_window').append(data);
   }`

The application is working as expected. The old chats are getting appended to the div before the new chats.